# Disable mouse clicks in gvim on ubuntu

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

How do I make gvim ignore mouse clicks. I'm really sick of the trackpad making my cursor all over the place. I use xubuntu if that means anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use:

```
:set mouse=c
```

This sets it to command-line mode. You can read about all of the options by typing,

```
:help mouse
```

To avoid needing to type the command each time, you can put it in your ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 3):

As akira said, you can disable the mouse entirely, but you can also selectively disable mouse buttons by mapping them to `<nop>`. For example, if it is just a problem in insert mode, and just the left mouse button:

```
:imap <LeftMouse> <nop>
```

You can even do it for double clicks:

```
:imap <2-LeftMouse> <nop>
```

See:

```
:help gui-mouse-mapping
:help map-overview
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:set mouse=
```

see also: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/term.html#mouse-using

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and though one can disable mouse/touchpad entirely there is a better solution: to disable touchpad while typing.

For Ubuntu there is a [how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad#Disabling_Touchpad_while_Typing).

Answer (score 0):

I am using set `so=1` in my .gvimrc or .vimrc under the gui section.
The other ones are for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> pasting, which is totally convenient in the gui.

```
if has('gui_running')
        vmap <C-c> "+yi
        vmap <C-x> "+c
        vmap <C-v> c<ESC>"+p
        imap <C-v> <C-r><C-o>+
        set so=1
endif
```